# Ошибка при выборе данных из MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

Как сделать выборку данных из MySQL?

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
import time
import pymysql
 
con = pymysql.connect('localhost', 'Admin', 'p6nO0OUp2M12123213213', 'Databse')
cur = con.cursor()

x = 2

while(True):
    print("Очередь аккаунта № " + str(x))
    cur.execute(f"SELECT PHONE FROM Account WHERE ID = '{x}'")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    Phone = str(cur.fetchall()[0])
    print("Входим в аккаунт: " + Phone)
    cur.execute(f"SELECT PASS FROM Account WHERE ID = '{x}'")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    password = str(cur.fetchall()[0])
    print(password)
    cur.execute(f"SELECT API_ID FROM Account WHERE ID = '{x}'")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    api_id = str(cur.fetchall()[0])
    cur.execute(f"SELECT API_HASH FROM Account WHERE ID = '{x}'")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    api_hash = str(cur.fetchall()[0])
    session = str("anon" + str(x))
    print(Phone, " номер")
    print(password, " пароль")
    print(api_id, " Api id")
    print(api_hash, " Хеш")
    client = TelegramClient(session, api_id, api_hash)
    client.start()
    x = x + 1
    time.sleep(1)
    if x == 32:
        print("Aккаунты активированы!")
        break
```

Ошибка

```
Входим в аккаунт: ('15543543545',)
('ASDFGH',)
('15543543545',)  номер
('ASDFGH',)  пароль
('14256',)  Api id
('632',)  Хеш
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "create_client.py", line 31, in <module>
    client = TelegramClient(session, api_id, api_hash)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telethon/client/telegrambaseclient.py", line 286, in __init__
    self.api_id = int(api_id)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "('14256',)"
```

Comment: думаю проблема в том что вы передаете кортеж вместо числового значения id попробуйте `api_id = ('14256',)
int_api_id, = api_id`

Comment: Смотрите, на примере `api_id = str(cur.fetchall()[0])`: во первых не стоит приводить к строке, а во вторых `fetchall` вернет список кортежей (даже если один элемент возвращает), и в-третьих, лучше использовать `fetchone`. Пример для `fetchall`: `api_hash = cur.fetchall()[0][0]` или так: `api_hash, = cur.fetchall()[0]`

Comment: Кроме того, запрос лучше делать с привязкой (гуглите про sql-инъекции), что-то вроде такого `cur.execute(f"SELECT API_ID FROM Account WHERE ID = ?", [x])`. Да и не понятно зачем делать запрос по одной и той же записи таблицы, вытаскивая поле по одному, ведь можно сразу вытащить все необходимые поля: `cur.execute(f"SELECT PHONE, PASS, API_ID, API_HASH FROM Account WHERE ID = ?", [x])`, тогда получение значения тех полей будет так: `phone, pass, api_id, api_hash = cur.fetchall()[0]`

Comment: @gil9red тогда уж лучше `fetchone()` и не запариваться с элементами списка

Comment: api_id = ('14256',) int_api_id, = api_id - Таже ошибка с верху.
fetchone - Не работает я пробовал его использовать.

Comment: cur.fetchall()[0][0]) - Вот это работает

Comment: @Namerek, ага, выше об этом я уже писал :) JleUTeHaHT, пожалуйста, оформите решение как ответ

Comment: Я еще на разобрался как что тут... И не знаю как сделать это :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну вот что-то такое у меня получилось из Вашего кода. Я бы конечно убрал все рюшки ввиде вывода вообще, но тут хозяин - барин

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient
import time
import pymysql

con = pymysql.connect('localhost', 'Admin', 'p6nO0OUp2M12123213213', 'Databse')
cur = con.cursor()

x = 2

cur.execute(f"SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Account")

accounts_qty, *_ = cur.fetchone()

while x < accounts_qty + 1:
    print(f"Очередь аккаунта № {x}")
    cur.execute(f"SELECT PHONE,PASS, API_ID, API_ID FROM Account WHERE ID = '{x}'")
    Phone, password, api_id, api_hash = cur.fetchone()

    print(f"Входим в аккаунт: {Phone}")
    time.sleep(1)
    session = str(f"anon{x}")
    print(f"{Phone} номер")
    print(f"{password} пароль")
    print(f"{api_id} Api id")
    print(f"{api_hash} Хеш")
    client = TelegramClient(session, api_id, api_hash)
    client.start()
    x += 1
    time.sleep(1)
else:
    print("Aккаунты активированы!")
```

**UPD** Небольшая фантазия "на тему":

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient
import time
import pymysql

con = pymysql.connect('localhost', 'Admin', 'p6nO0OUp2M12123213213', 'Databse')
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute(f"SELECT ID, PHONE, PASS, API_ID, API_ID FROM Account;")
accounts = cur.fetchall()

activated_accounts = []
fail_activation = dict()

for account in accounts:
    id_, phone, password, api_id, api_hash = account
    try:
        TelegramClient(f'anon{id_}', api_id, api_hash).start()
        activated_accounts += [id_]
    except Exception as err:
        fail_activation.update(
            {
                id_: err
            }
        ) 
    time.sleep(1)

if activated_accounts:
    success_report = '\n'.join(activated_accounts)
    print(f"Аккаунты\n{success_report}\nУспешно активированы!")
if fail_activation:

    fail_print_str = '\n'.join(
        ['-'] * 30 + [
            f'Аккаунт {i} не активирован. Причина: {e}' for i, e in [error for error in fail_activation.items()]
        ]
    )
    print(fail_print_str)
```

Comment: Я бы предложил так: `cur.execute(f"SELECT PHONE,PASS, API_ID, API_ID FROM Account WHERE ID = %s", [x])` и тут лишний вызов `str`: `session = str(f"anon{x}")`. Сбивает с толку, что в `pymysql` параметры в шаблонах sql не через `?` задаются: https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html

Comment: @gil9red. Да там по хорошему весь код в 4 (условно) строки записать можно. Я не стал его оптимизировать, так подшаманил немного. По хорошему, там еще в `try` кое что обернуть не мешает